# web.config - "This file has been modified outside the source editor" after every build?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-profiles

I have inherited an asp.net-mvc3 project and the webconfig in the project folder is getting modified (set to a default/fixed set of config items) on every build. I thought that was due to conditional xslt config transforms but it's not.  It doesn't matter what I have in the transformed web.debug.config as it doesn't overwrite what is generated in the webconfig.

Every time I modify the webconfig I get the dialog nag that "this file as been modifed outside the source editor" after each build.

Could this be in custom build settings?  I'm totally at a loss here.

Comment: Any post build events on your project?

Comment: @vcsjones: Hi, nothing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any Post or Pre build events in your properties:

[image]